# Como ordenar uma lista de objetos em dart?

Tags: classificação, flutter, dart

```
Future<void> _getAllPesagens() async {
    List<Pesagem> pesagemFinal = List();
    await pesagemHelper.getAllPesagems().then((listaP) {
      print(listaP);
      if (listaP.isNotEmpty) {
        for (var peso in listaP) {
          if (peso.animalId == _caprinoSelecionado.idAnimal) {
            pesagemFinal.add(peso);
          }
        }
        setState(() {
          Comparator<Pesagem> pesagemComparator =
              (a, b) => b.data.compareTo(a.data);
          pesagemFinal.sort(pesagemComparator);
          pesagemFinal.forEach((Pesagem item) {
            print('${item.idPesagem} - ${item.data} - ${item.peso}');
          });
          pesos = pesagemFinal;
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

Esse é o código que pega do banco de dados todas as Pesagens feitas pelo usuário, Pesagem é um objeto que tem o atributo DATA como String no formato de dd/mm/yyyy, tentei utilizar o comparator para ordenar a lista de pesagens a partir da data, porem o resultado retornado foi o seguinte:

[image: Ele ordena apenas parte da lista, o que não é o que eu queria]

Ele ordena apenas parte da lista, o que não é o que eu queria

Comment: O problema da sua ordenação é que foi feita com String. Caso deseje ordenar por datas a primeira coisa que precisará é converter a `String` da data em um tipo `DateTime` e somente depois fazer a ordenação. Existem diversas formas de fazer essa conversão, é só pesquisar "String to DateTime dart" no google. Como seu código está com apenas um trecho não vou montar um exemplo funcional para exemplificar. Mas basicamente é apenas esse processo que deverá fazer para corrigir.

Comment: Aqui resolveu, valeu mesmo !!

Comment: Disponha... Inseri uma resposta para que possa servir de guia para consultas futuras do pessoal da comunidade. Assim poderá ser marcada como resposta aceita indicando um caminho a se seguir. Se possível sinalize nela a resposta aceita.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema no seu caso é somente o tipo de dados que está utilizando para ordenação. No formato atual que está codificado a ordem está correta observando-se o tipo `String` que são textos comuns.

Como deseja ordenar pela data, o que precisa fazer é, primeiro, converter as datas de `String` para o formato `DateTime` e a ordenação que deseja poderá ser feita corretamente.

Answer (score 0):

Você também pode inverter a posição dos comparadores e converter para string, ficando assim

//ANTES
`(a, b) => b.data.compareTo(a.data);`

//DEPOIS
`(a, b) => a.data.toString.compareTo(b.data.toString);`
Vai trazer na ordem dos mais antigos primeiro`(a, b) => b.data.toString.compareTo(a.data.toString);`
Vai trazer os mais recentes primeiro